# Can't Send PHPMailer with Oauth Google

Tags: php, email, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, phpmailer

I have some problem.
My code

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$userEmail = "mail@mail.org";
$clientId = "xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com";
$clientSecret = "xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx";
$token = "1/xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-5EmWcSmuvnRbJs";

$mailer = new PHPMailerOAuth;
$mailer->isSMTP();
$mailer->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mailer->SMTPAuth = true;
$mailer->AuthType = 'XOAUTH2';
$mailer->oauthUserEmail = $userEmail;
$mailer->oauthClientId = $clientId;
$mailer->oauthClientSecret = $clientSecret;
$mailer->oauthRefreshToken = $token;
$mailer->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mailer->Port = 587;

$mailer->setFrom("xxxxx@xxxxxxx.org");
$mailer->addAddress("xxxxxx@gmail.com");

$mailer->Subject = "Subject";
$mailer->Body = "Message";

if (! $mailer->send())
    throw new RuntimeException('Mail submission failed! ' . $mailer->ErrorInfo);
```

This eror

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Google' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/mailer/PHPMailer/class.phpmaileroauthgoogle.php:54 Stack trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/mailer/PHPMailer/class.phpmaileroauthgoogle.php(67): PHPMailerOAuthGoogle->getProvider() #1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/mailer/PHPMailer/class.phpmaileroauthgoogle.php(74): PHPMailerOAuthGoogle->getToken() #2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/mailer/PHPMailer/class.smtp.php(470): PHPMailerOAuthGoogle->getOauth64() #3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/mailer/PHPMailer/class.phpmaileroauth.php(174): SMTP->authenticate('', '', 'XOAUTH2', '', '', Object(PHPMailerOAuthGoogle)) #4 /opt/lampp/htdocs/mailer/PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php(1540): PHPMailerOAuth->smtpConnect(Array) #5 /opt/lampp/htdocs/mailer/PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php(1335): PHPMailer->smtpSend('Date: Thu, 3 Au...', 'Message\n') #6 /opt/lampp/htdocs/mailer/PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php(1213): PHPMailer->postSend() #7 /opt/lampp/htdocs/mailer/index.php(27): PHPMailer->send() #8 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/mailer/PHPMailer/class.phpmaileroauthgoogle.php on line 54
```

i don't know what my mistake, i just want to create mail with PHPmailer using google smtp with Oauth2.0, I've searched on google but I have not found the solution yet

Comment: Have you run `composer install`? Also, where is your `require '../vendor/autoload.php'`? Unless you've got a framework handling this for you, that has to be included.

Comment: yeah, i done run composer install

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [PHPMailer's composer.json file](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/composer.json#L47) - it includes the OAuth class as a **suggestion**, because it's not a requirement, and won't work on older PHP versions that PHPMailer supports, so it can't be enabled by default.

You need to add it to your own composer.json file (the same one you load PHPMailer with).

I've added comments to this effect to the [Gmail OAuth2 tutorial on the PHPMailer wiki](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Using-Gmail-with-XOAUTH2).

While I'm here, I suggest you don't implement this using PHPMailer 5.2, but go directly to [PHPMailer 6.0](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/tree/6.0) which has much better support for OAuth2.

Comment: hai i have question in my problem again in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45499897/cant-send-email-phpmailer-6-0-with-oauth-google @Synchro

Comment: Google now requires that each redirect URI be whitelisted. This is an additional step not covered in your wiki article.

Comment: Sounds like an excellent opportunity for you to contribute your knowledge to an open source project, given that the wiki is publicly editable.