# Can't Send Email PHPMailer 6.0 with Oauth Google

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, phpmailer, google-oauth

0 with Google Oauth and i get this error

```
2017-08-04 06:38:42 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP v19sm895098pgc.93 - gsmtp
2017-08-04 06:38:42 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
2017-08-04 06:38:43 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [180.243.143.147]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-STARTTLS250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
2017-08-04 06:38:43 CLIENT ->; SERVER: STARTTLS
2017-08-04 06:38:43 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
2017-08-04 06:38:43 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
2017-08-04 06:38:43 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [180.243.143.147]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
2017-08-04 06:38:43 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2017-08-04 06:38:43 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 closing connection v19sm895098pgc.93 - gsmtp
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

My script

```
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require './vendor/autoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';

$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->AuthType = 'XOAUTH2';

$mail->oauthUserEmail = "info@modelunitednation.org";
$mail->oauthClientId = "932857915584-eco8v9aejdb2n3mkltgvftf8e5h1eiko.apps.googleusercontent.com";
$mail->oauthClientSecret = "7SqFo7aPYvZ05cHlh5p3kMUD";
$mail->oauthRefreshToken = "1/4KJJ5XMyXqELMAhRXGYjz_I4SfoWfFR9N9RRA2VA2I0";

$mail->addAddress('jakabanasuy2@gmail.com');     // Add a recipient
$mail->isHTML(true);                               // Set email format to HTML
$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');
$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

i don't have any idea, i've done search google but i dont find any solution. Before i ask in [Can't Send PHPMailer with Oauth Google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45493112/cant-send-phpmailer-with-oauth-google)

Any solution for my case?

Comment: If you're going to use the 6.0 branch, use [the oauth example from the same branch](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/6.0/examples/gmail_xoauth.phps); it doesn't work the same way it used to.

Comment: Thanks :) its work for me

Answer (score 0):

For `XOAUTH2` AuthType, if you are using the [5.2 version](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/5.2-stable/examples/gmail_xoauth.phps), you are instantiating the *wrong class*. [The 6.0](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/6.0/examples/gmail_xoauth.phps) also works different.

You should use:

`$mail = new PHPMailerOAuth;`

That is the reason of the following error:

> 2017-08-04 06:38:43 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your
>   service, [180...... XOAUTH2 ......
>   **SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.**

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

First, OAuth is really hard to debug anyway. I really recommend that you take a look at the [6.0 branch](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/tree/6.0), in which the OAuth support is significantly improved. It comes with much better examples, and it would be very useful if you could help test it. This second step is key point and might solve your problem. There is slight difference in initiation( Use `PHPMailerOAuth` class), so please read the docs carefully.

Second, Go through [this](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Using-Gmail-with-XOAUTH2) documentation, you might have followed it, but see if you are missing any step.

Third, Are you sure you got a refresh token and not a normal token?

Try these things and let me know, if it worked for you or not?